# Populating joiner table from two other tables

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables

```
Node
- NodeID

Role
- RoleID

NodeRoles
- NodeID
- RoleID
```

For every record in NodeID I'd like to create a record in NodeRoles against every record in table Role.

this was my attempt at solving the above.

```
INSERT INTO NodeRoles (NodeID, RoleID)
VALUES ( SELECT NodeID from Node, SELECT RoleID from Role )
```

This seems like a simple approach and the idea feels right, but the error that comes back is that we're reporting multiple values into a singluar column. Which reviewing that makes sense as that's exactly what is happening.

In application code I would simply set up two foreach loops, but I'm not sure how to get the same thing in SQL. Thank you!

Comment: `select nodeid, roleid from Node, Role`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO NodeRoles (NodeID, RoleID)
( SELECT NodeID,RoleID from Node,Role )
```